# EFCore generates phantom column name in select

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I am upgrading a project to EFCore 2.2.0 from 2.1.3 and encountered this bizarre issue. When loading data for a simple table, I get an exception that 'ExchangeCd1' is not defined. This column does not exist, but it is not referenced anywhere in the code. When I examine the mapping properties, I see it is listed as: 
    {Property: ExchangeHoliday.ExchangeCd1 (no field, string) Shadow FK Index 2 2 2 0 1}

The classes are pretty simple, but the child has a composite primary key and the parent tries to reference it using its individual key.

```
public class Exchange
{
    public string ExchangeCd { get; set; }

    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }

    public DayOfWeek WeekendStart { get; set; }

    public DayOfWeek WeekendEnd { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExchangeHoliday> Holidays { get; set; }
}

public class ExchangeHoliday
{
    public string ExchangeCd { get; set; }

    public DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsTradeHoliday { get; set; }

    public bool IsSettleHoliday { get; set; }
}
```

I add some mapping, in order to define the primary key as a composite key

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Exchange>().HasKey(e => e.ExchangeCd);
modelBuilder.Entity<ExchangeHoliday>().HasKey(e => new { e.ExchangeCd, e.HolidayDate });
```

Then I execute a very simple select

```
var holidays = await dbContext.ExchangeHolidays.ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I turned on EFCore SQL logging, and it generates this for the SQL

```
SELECT [e].[exchange_cd], [e].[holiday_date], [e].[ExchangeCd1], [e].[is_settle_holiday], [e].[is_trade_holiday]
FROM [exchange_holiday] AS [e]
```

I tried to add explicit mapping to remove the shadow key, but it sticks around

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Exchange>()
                    .HasMany<ExchangeHoliday>()
                    .WithOne(e => e.Exchange)
                    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ExchangeCd);
```

Comment: Your code above is incomplete (missing mappings you defined), otherwise, how would EF know that `HolidayDate` is actually `holiday_date`.

Comment: I have generic mapping on names. I added it to the example, but it is irrlevant

Comment: are you sure there isn't a bug in your column name conversion? - Try using the same names in your class without the conversion logic and see if that solves it, if so it will help you narrow down where the bug is, if not, then other users of this version should be running into this too.

Comment: No there is no issue in the name conversion. I found the issues, it is the relationship with the parent, which I did not include in the example. Something must have changed in EFCore for relationship mapping between 2.1.3 where it works, and 2.2.0 where it is broken

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if I do the mapping on the child, it resolves the issue

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExchangeHoliday>()
                    .HasOne<Exchange>()
                    .WithMany(e => e.Holidays)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExchangeCd);
```